# Orthogonal Projections in Hilbert Spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, projection

Let $H$ be a Hilbert Space and let $K \subset H$ be a non-empty closed convex set in $H.$ Let $P_K: H \mapsto K$ be the orthogonal projection of $H$ onto $K,$ so $P_K(u)$ is the distance minimizing vector in $K,$ namely,

$$||P_K(u)-u||_H\leq ||v-u||_H$$

for all $v \in K.$

I have two questions:

1. In general, is this map linear ( the text I am reading makes no mention of this and I am wondering if it is well known or not true)? If not, is there a topological or linear-algebraic classification of spaces on which this map is linear. (I am aware that this map is non-expansive and continuous in the norm on $H$).
2. Is there an orthogonality (with respect to the inner product on $H$) relationship between $P_K(x)$ and $P_K(-x).$

This is not homework, it just pertains to something I am currently studying. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Consider $K=[-1,2]\subset \mathbb{R}=H$. Then $P(x)=x$ for $x\in [-1,2]$, while $P(x)=1$ for $x>2$. Also $P(1)=1$ while $P(-1)=-1$.

Comment: If $K$ is a subspace, $P_K$ can be shown to be linear. As the comment above shows, this is false in general. In fact, 2. would be "no relationship" in general, finding examples in $\mathbf{R}^2$ should be easy.

Comment: Thank you both for the helpful answers. Do either of you know if this changes if I further impose that $K$ is a non-empty, closed, convex cone?